# Is there a way to use Core MIDI on pre iOS 4.2 devices?

Tags: ios, midi

Say, I build my app using iphoneos4.2 as the Base SDK. Will the Core MIDI part work on older devices? I suppose not, but is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because CoreMIDI was only introduced in 4.2, older versions of the OS don't contain the framework and so cannot use it.  You could use something like DSMidiWiFi as a substitute.